# read the first line of the txt file then delete that line with php

Tags: php, file, line

I have a huge txt file that have 475254 lines and with php I want to read the first line of the my txt file and save it into the Variable and then when I save it the php delete that line.
my txt file is about 2.3 MB is it possible to do this?

Comment: Yes.  What have you tried so far that is failing?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: It *may be* possible. Quasi-Edit: never mind. Both comments above say the same thing, including almost the same character length; coing-kah-dink? *Go figure*.

Comment: Careful guys, the file is 2.3 MG and there may be no way to even open a file of that size. ;)

Comment: What's an `MG`, that British-made cutie of a car? Or did you mean `MB`? Mega GIG? ouch; doubt it.

Comment: please dear god tell us what you have tried and the errors you're getting!

Comment: You might get away in using [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it is /.................................

OK less trolling..

You want fopen  and fgets will grab a line. REF : [fgets Manual PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php)

```
$file = "file.txt"
$f = fopen($file, 'r');
$line = fgets($f);
fclose($f); // You close because you only want the first one.
```

There are so many examples how to do this i feel embarrassed answering. You should show some of what you have tried first!

Now you want to remove it: use file_get_contents REF : [PHP file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
//Get your file contents

$newDoc = file_get_contents($file, true);
$newFileContents = substr( $line, strpos($newDoc, "\n")+1 );
//then you want to save it 
file_put_contents($newFileContents, $file);
```

I might be wrong but you get the idea!~ ;)

Process :

1. Get Contents of file
2. Get First Line
3. Replace content of all file with your First Line as New Line
4. Save File

Im sure there is a more efficient way to do this, im just winging!

**NOTE:** You may need to configure your php.ini to work with larger files!

Comment: I'm almost tempted to +1 this.

Comment: the question was answered!

Comment: LOL I was tempted to *-1 this*... but I won't because it is a direct answer to the question!

Comment: @MarkM ok ok i entertained him||her!

Comment: @Pogrindis: You've gone and spoilt it now. I'm retracting my +1 because he wants to delete the line that was read. RTFQ!

Comment: @TheBlueDog lel ok ill fix this, jesus talk about holding hands! :D

Comment: Sidenote: Extra quote in `('$file, true)`

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks, was wondering why the formatting was wrong.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your great answer, the first part that get first line work correctly but the next part that remove the first line not working and I really don't know how can I worked with files because I don't like :D , Can you help me to make this correct?

Answer (score 1):

yes, Mark is probably too lazy to even try bulid a code, but i have already a working code so.. copypasta

```
$file = "mydata.txt";
$f = fopen($file, 'r');
$line = fgets($f);
fclose($f);

//do smth

$contents = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$first_line = array_shift($contents);
file_put_contents($file, implode("\r\n", $contents));
//sleep(1);
```